# reduce current time from input time

Tags: c#, time, window

I need to reduce user input time from current time how should i do?
C# windows

Ex-

- current time - 1:05:10
- input time ---- 1:03:05
- i need    --------  0:02:05

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write a static Method I know this works and it will handle doing what it is you need to do

I have shown an example of how to call it but you will pass in actual DateTime startTime and endTime values. `TimeSpan` will give you a more accurate Time

```
public static TimeSpan GetTimeSpan(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    TimeSpan totTime = new TimeSpan();
    startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());
    endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(endTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());
    totTime = (TimeSpan)(endTime - startTime);
    return totTime;
}
```

Usage of for calling the method Replace the Convert code and assign actual DateTime values for `DateTime.Now for inputTime and when Ending use DateTime.Now to assign endInputTime`
I have used this as a test example to show you how to get Duration using `TimeSpan`

```
var inputTime = Convert.ToDateTime("1:03:05");
var endInputTime = Convert.ToDateTime("1:05:10");
var newTimeSpan = GetTimeSpan(inputTime, endInputTime);
```

yields - `{00:02:05}`

Answer (score 1):

From localized time:

```
Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(inputTime).ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

From UTC:

```
Text = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(inputTime).ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(inputTime).ToString();
```